# 500 Internal Server Error : .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm getting the following error

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@localhost and
>   inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might
>   have done that may have caused the error. More information about this
>   error may be available in the server error log. Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
>   Server at 111.118.254.188 Port 80

Im running a XAMPP server here is my htaccess file, I don't understand what the problem is.

```
# Customized error messages.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What is the file permission to your .htaccess file?

Comment: What is your Apache logs saying?

Comment: start commenting out line by line and see where is the problematic line I guess is the first 2 lines

Comment: I think you are not running mod_rewrite http://www.leonardaustin.com/blog/technical/enable-mod_rewrite-in-xampp/

Comment: try this ErrorDocument 404 http://yourdomain/index.php  instead of ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

Comment: For security reasons, Apache is not configured to display actual error messages for public display. You need to check the server logs in order to see what the actual error is. Please don't just make changes blindly until you happen to succeed.

Comment: @talsibony - Please note the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` part. Just not running mod_rewrite should not trigger a 500 status code.

Comment: There are numerous reasons a 500 error can be thrown, even an error in your php file. The first step would be to check your error logs. And try to rename your .htaccess to be sure it's the .htaccess file that's causing the error.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I know that, as far as I know ErrorDocument also depends on mod_rewrite and it is outside the condition

Comment: [It doesn't](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#errordocument).

Comment: I just dropped that code into an .htaccess file on my dev box and it didn't throw up any errors - I suspect what's triggering the error may be elsewhere.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario You are right it is not depends on it as I though, double checked it without mod_rewrite and its running,

Answer (score -1):

You should add RewriteBase to define the per-directory prefix.

Also try adding :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```